# Count JSON keys using dynamic column names

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to count the keys in a JSON field based a predefined list of keys.

All possible keys are in a table called `targeting`.

| keys |
| --- |
| LOCATION |
| AGE |
| INTEREST |

Now I want to be able to count occurrences of each of these keys by a group in a `postimpressions` table.

| advertiserId | targetingData |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { LOCATION: 'UK', AGE: '100' } |
| 1 | { INTEREST: 'SQL' } |

With a query that looks like this, but the key part is I'd like to generate the count columns dynamically from the `targeting` table.

```sql
SELECT
  "advertiserId",
  count(*) AS TOTAL_ADS,
  count("targetingData" -> 'LOCATION') AS LOCATION,
  count("targetingData" -> 'AGE') AS AGE
  --- and again for each in targeting_types
FROM
  postimpressions
GROUP BY
  "advertiserId"
;
```

Comment: Not possible. The number, types and names of a SQL query must be known when the query is parsed. They can't depend on results returned by the query itself